# AS3 - Properly reference a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, scope, movieclip

So, I have this Player.as class file with the following code:

```
private function PressAKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
 {
   getDistance();
   if(event.keyCode == 32 && placedBomb == false && bombNumber == 0)//space
 {
   xKey = true;
   placeBomb();
   placedBomb = true;
}
}
```

Using this in conjunction with the following placeBomb() function:

```
private function placeBomb():void{

 MainClass.container.addChildAt(bomb,0);
 bomb.x = this.x;
 bomb.y = this.y+20;
 bombNumber ++;
}
```

The problem comes from this function which is trying to calculate the distance between the player and the bomb so that I can start building interactions:

```
private function getDistance():void{
 distance = Math.sqrt( ( this.x - MainClass.container.bomb.x ) * ( this.x - MainClass.container.bomb.x ) + ( this.y - MainClass.container.bomb.y ) * ( this.y - MainClass.container.bomb.y ) );
 trace(distance);
}
```

I get this error when I try this:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at Player/getDistance()
at Player/PressAKey()
```

Do you have any idea what I'm missing? It's definitely a scoping issue, so what would I need to include in order for the entire class to recognize the bomb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bomb` is no property of `MainClass.container`. `bomb` is a only child.

refer a following code.

```
private function getDistance():void
{
   var bomb:DisplayObject = MainClass.container.getChildAt(0);

   distance = Math.sqrt( ( this.x - bomb.x ) * ( this.x - bomb.x ) + ( this.y - bomb.y ) * ( this.y - bomb.y ) );
   trace(distance);
}
```

### How to reference all the children.

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<parentObject.numChildren; i++)
{ 
   var object:DisplayObject = parentObject.getChildAt(i);
   /*
   p.s: if a child object type is MovieClip. must be typecasting.
   var object:MovieClip = parentObject.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
   */
}
```

Comment: Excellent. That referenced it and the code is working. Is this how I reference all variables that are outside the scope?